# Trouble authenticating a request to a Google Workflows callback from a Cloud Function

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth, google-workflows

I have a data pipeline set up with Google Workflows where I have a step to wait for a Cloud Function that is triggered from Pub/Sub to complete by using the callback mechanism documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/creating-callback-endpoints).

The Workflow and Cloud Function are both deployed with the same service account (which has the Workflows Invoker role) and are in the same project.

I am getting the following HTTP error when I try and call the callback URL:
`requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://workflowexecutions.googleapis.com/v1/projects`

The Workflow is defined like so:

```
main:
  steps:
    - init:
        assign:
          - project: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
    - create-callback:
        call: events.create_callback_endpoint
        args:
            http_callback_method: "GET"
        result: callback_load
    - init-callback:
        assign:
          - message: {"name": "check_load_finished", "callback": "${callback_load.url}"}
          - base64Msg: ${base64.encode(json.encode(message))}
    - check-load-finished:
        call: googleapis.pubsub.v1.projects.topics.publish
        args:
          topic: ${"projects/" + project + "/topics/data-scripts"}
          body:
            messages:
              - data: ${base64Msg}
    - await-callback:
        call: events.await_callback
        args:
            callback: ${callback_load}
            timeout: 1200
        result: callback_request
```

The cloud function calls the following function after it has finished operation:

```
import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token
import requests

def send_callback(callback_url):
    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, callback_url)
    print(f"ID Token: {id_token}")

    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {id_token}",
    }

    r = requests.get(
        url=callback_url,
        headers=headers,
    )
    r.raise_for_status()
    print(f"Callback sent to '{callback_url}'")
```

I used [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#generating_tokens_programmatically) reference to try to get the access token from within the Cloud Function.

Any help appreciated!

TL/DR;

- I have tried to generate the access token programatically within the Cloud Function as implied [here](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/creating-callback-endpoints#generate_an_oauth_token_for_a) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#generating_tokens_programmatically)
- I expected to be able to request the callback URL from within the Cloud Function so that the Workflow will continue
- I instead get an HTTPError `401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url`

Comment: What's the permission of the Coud Function runtime service account? You shouldn't have the role "Workflows Invoker role" on it. That's the reason!

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trial and error, here is the solution to the above if anyone runs into this:

```
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.credentials

def generate_access_token():
    credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(
        scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
    )
    request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    credentials.refresh(request)
    access_token = credentials.token
    return access_token
```

Comment: I wanted to do the same, reason: calling (http) a cloud function from a workflow only wait for 1800 seconds and I needed to push it to 3600. 
But! Coud function triggered with pup/sub only run for 540 seconds (and not 3600).
So I'm screw either way (if ever it occur you to do the same don't waste time prior checking cloud function subtleties)